Godot 4.2.2 .NET. Broken chunk loader
I'm making the educational project (game with like minecraft terrain) and I'm having trouble generatng or chunk loading.
Generator is works properly, created chunks adding to dictionary where key is Vector2I (chunk position) and value is instance of chunk and when loading chunks from a dictionary, most often a re-generation occurs, which damages the recorded data. I don't understand why this is happening. I suppose it's because of the threads, but if disable the dictionary, it works stably.
Chunk loader works in not stable. If create a new game (without exit from scene) then the area will load as it was.
The files with the code are located in the following path: scripts/terrain.
Github repository
Click me
Click me
I expect the chunk loader to load written chunks from memory without losing data.
Perhaps I broke the logic when trying to load a chunk from the list.
Thank you in advance!
